# parsing a string using fscanf using %[...] in C

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I am working with the `fscanf` function to scan in a large string that is delimited by commas, with the last substring in the larger string separated by an asterisk (*). Here is an example:

```
substring1,substring2,substring3*substring4
```

I am able to parse the substrings separated by commas with no problem, but when it gets to the asterisk, it stalls the program, as `fscanf` is blocking. I am using the `%[^...]` format specifier in `fscanf`, shown below:

```
fscanf(fs, "%[^*,]%*c", str);
```

The code above is in a simple for loop that scans multiple times. As you can see, I am scanning until either an asterisk or a comma appears. However, I am afraid that I am not including the asterisk in the set properly. Can someone correct my mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only characters that are special in a `%[` pattern are `^`, `-`, and `]`.

This pattern will fail if the next character to be read is either a `','` or a `'*'`.  So if you have two consecutive commas or asterisks, then your loop will jam and stop reading.